# Using invariant with Dexterity form and fieldsets

Tags: validation, plone, dexterity

I have a content type derived from plone.directives.form.Schema; it has several dozen fields across four fieldsets. I'm trying to create a zope.interface.invariant that looks at fields from two different fieldsets.

From tracing the behaviour, it looks like the invariant is called once for *each* fieldset, but not for the entire form.

I'm aware I can provide my own handler and perform all the checks I need there, but that feels chunky compared to distinctly defined invariants. While the obvious solution is to move related fields onto the same fieldset, the current setup reflects a layout that is logical the end user.

Is there an existing hook where I could perform validation on multiple fields across fieldsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be no: `z3c.form.group.Group.extractData` calls `z3c.form.form.BaseForm.extractData` once for each group/fieldset, and this call already includes invariant validation.

Instead of registering your own *handler*, you could also overwrite *extractData*:

```
from plone.directives import form, dexterity
from z3c.form.interfaces import ActionExecutionError,WidgetActionExecutionError
# ...

class EditForm(dexterity.EditForm):
  grok.context(IMyEvent)

  def extractData(self, setErrors=True):
    data, errors = super(EditForm, self).extractData(setErrors)

    if not None in(data['start'], data['end']):
      if data['end'] < data['start']:
        raise WidgetActionExecutionError('end', Invalid(_(u"End date should not lie before the start date.")))
      if data['end'] - data['start'] > datetime.timedelta(days=7):
        raise WidgetActionExecutionError('end', Invalid(_(u"Duration of convention should be shorter than seven (7) days.")))

    return data, errors
```

Please note that this class derives from dexterity.EditForm, which includes Dexterity's default handlers, instead of form.SchemaForm.

`WidgetActionExecutionError` does not work reliably, though. For some fields, it produces a 'KeyError'.